# How to implement full advertisement using greystrip sdk?

Tags: iphone

I want to display a full advertisement in my application. I don't know how to implement it. I know this is possible using greystrip sdk. Can you give me advice?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basic documentation with examples can be found at: http://wiki.greystripe.com/index.php/Greystripe_SDK

You should start there and then ask more specific questions when you hit problems.